# I want to Update List of Items before setting it to RecyclerView Adapter. List is coming from server (Android, Kotlin) [THIS IS CLOSED]

Tags: android, list, api, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am working on a project. The scenario is that I am receiving a list of items from server. Before setting it to recycler-view adapter I am checking that is the items are deleted by the user or not, if the items deleted then data of deleted items like itemId, deletedItemsCount, customerId will store in local Database. Then getting the deleted items of specific product from database and subtract it from the total items receiving from server and then update the specific item in the list and then setting it to adapter.

The easy way to understand the scenario is (steps)

- receiving list of products from server
- by getting data from local database check if the items deleted or not
- if yes, then store the deleted items of specific product in local database
- get the deleted items from local database and subtract it from items receiving server
- update that server list before setting it to adapter
- then set it to adapter

The **Problem is that** when the user delete the items by clicking deleted icon, it updates all product's items in the list. It should update that specific product's items of which the user clicked on the delete icon.

The screenshots and the code snippets attached for your reference.
Any type of suggestion would be helpful.
Thank you.

```
mainLocalViewModel.getAllDeletedItems().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

        viewModel.customerOrdersList.clear()

        for (items in viewModel.serverCustomerOrderList) {
            viewModel.customerOrdersList.add(items as OrderItemModel)
        }

        if (it != null && it.isNotEmpty()) {

            for (itemsInDb in it) {

                for ((index, itemsInServer) in viewModel.customerOrdersList.withIndex()) {

                    if (itemsInDb.itemId == itemsInServer.itemId && itemsInDb.customerId == viewModel.customerId) {

                        val totalInServer = itemsInServer.itemTotal
                        val totalInDb = itemsInDb.deletedItems

                        val remainingTotalItems = totalInDb?.let { it1 ->
                            totalInServer?.minus(
                                it1
                            )
                        }

                        viewModel.customerOrdersList[index].itemTotal = remainingTotalItems

                        if (::customerOrdersAdapter.isInitialized) {
                            customerOrdersAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index)
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            if (!::customerOrdersAdapter.isInitialized) {

                customerOrdersAdapter =
                    CustomerOrdersAdapter(
                        requireContext(),
                        viewModel.customerOrdersList,
                        this
                    )

                binding.apply {
                    recyclerViewCustomerOrder.apply {
                        layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2)
                        adapter = customerOrdersAdapter
                    }
                }

            }


        }
```

[Screenshot of the database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YeZC.png)

[Screenshot of List receiving from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uRJw.png)

[Screenshot of user delete dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d97Oe.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to checkout DiffUtil like in this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/21954410-speed-up-your-android-recyclerview-using-diffutil

It's basically a class that compares every two items of your list and calculates the difference between the old and new list of data, that way if you only delete one item, it should just update that item from the list.